# I did a oil change but forgot to drain the pan and now I have oil leaking through air intake

Tags: oil-change, acura, tl

It's blowing out thick white smoke and rattling pretty hard, I have motor oil coming out of my air intake and I can't put the air conditioning on cause it just shut the car off. I don't know what to do! And I need it for work. It's a 2003 Acura TL 3.2 v6 engine

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you're having such a hard time. This should be pretty simple. Just drain the oil. Fill it back to the recommended level and then run it. You'll have some slight after effects, but it should be fine. It isn't good to run your engine with extra oil (especially not double the amount). It can cause damage to an extent, but I doubt there's any serious damage. The best you can do is just drain all the oil (get a big pan) and then replace with the recommended amount.

Comment: Appreciate it, also I drained everything and put new oil but for some reason it's still doing it, not coming out of the air intake but like blowing white smoke and rattling pretty hard. I feel it might be the gasket or pcv maybe? I just really hope it's nothing serious, it's not over heating either and the coolant is still at the same place.

Comment: You could just be burning off oil that has got into your air intake etc.  However, you could also have caused damage to your pistons, con rods, or piston rings due to the pistons hitting against the overfilled oil in the sump.

Comment: @GenovanniNoble - Agree with HandyHowie here ... if you now have the recommended amount of oil in the engine, the best you can do is to run your vehicle a bit to see if it settles out some. If it doesn't, you may have caused permanent engine damage. If it does settle down, you should be in okay shape.